# Breadcrump with css

Tags: html, css

In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u52m2ohg/) I create a simple breadcrumb. I like to change the dependencies of class "div.arrow-right". I like to control the arrow size by "#sequence". So that the size of the arrow belongs to the font-size. That means if I change the font-size the right-arrow should fit automatically the same high as the div which contains the writing.

```
#sequence {
  font-size: 28px;
 }
```

And I like to add a gap or lets say a white thin arrow between two breadcrumb elements, see the picture below.

[image]

Comment: So, what are you asking?

Comment: Here is a good example https://css-tricks.com/triangle-breadcrumbs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate using `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements. [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/u52m2ohg/3/)

```css
.breadcrumb {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 28px;
}
.breadcrumb li {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px 0 8px 50px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.breadcrumb li:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid #74c476;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
.breadcrumb li:before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
li:nth-child(1) {
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: #74c476;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #61a362;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #518851;
}
li:nth-child(1):after {
  border-left-color: #74c476;
}
li:nth-child(2):after {
  border-left-color: #61a362;
}
li:nth-child(3):after {
  border-left-color: #518851;
}
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>operator</li>
  <li>layout</li>
</ul>
```